# Client proxy makes Duplex TCP connection. Can only make 5 proxy client instances

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a working server-client setup with clients instantiated using a proxy. The server exposes endpoint using `netTcpBinding`. The binding's `maxConnections` is not configured and therefore I understand that the default value is 10. I'm not able to make more than 5 client instances.

**My question**.... Because it is a duplex connection, am I right to understand that all 10 connections are taken up by the 5 clients? So the right way to word this would be 10 channels and 5 connections in each direction? I'm not able to get conclusive documentation of this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplex means two connections per WCF duplex channel, yes. So five "connections" would be ten physical tcp connections.